Source for minhag to not eat whole hard boiled eggs?
I know people (including myself) who don't eat whole hard-boiled eggs, i.e. after boiling the egg they cut the egg in half or quarters and then eat it. The reason I heard was that eating an egg whole represents minhag aveilut, since aveilim eat whole hard-boiled eggs.
Is there a source for this minhag?
I have had this question for many years already, I searched many sefarim and have found nothing, and asked many people but have not got an answer, I would really happy if someone knows the answer :)

(Why) do aveilim eat whole hard-boiled eggs?

@magicker72 It emphasizes that "life" is a complete cycle, including reincarnation and resurrection. This is the deeper meaning of BeMidbar 14:28, חי אני נאם יהוה. "Chai" as contrasted to "Chaim".

For the sake of clarity, the custom you refer to is to cut it first rather than bite directly into it? Surely everyone would agree with trying to eat a whole hard boiled egg at once is potentially dangerous (and thus likely forbidden).

Yes, the custom is to cut it first rather than bite directly into it, not to eat a full egg in one go

Thanks for the clarification... which community has this custom?

I'm not sure, but my grandmother who is Iraqi has this custom, and she doesn't know where the minhag came from, could be other communities have this too
